# The fit() function in class ImageClassifier in Auto-Keras didn't run well

Tags: keras, mnist, auto-keras

I tried to run [auto-keras](https://github.com/jhfjhfj1/autokeras/issues/38) in a demo, but it failed, the code as shown below:

````
from keras.datasets import mnist
from autokeras.classifier import ImageClassifier

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

clf = ImageClassifier(verbose=True)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, time_limit=12 * 60 * 60)
clf.final_fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, retrain=True)
y = clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(y)
```
````

The error message as shown below:

````
```
Initializing search.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-077a1b1d90e1> in <module>()
      1 clf = ImageClassifier(verbose=True)
----> 2 clf.fit(x_train, y_train, time_limit=12 * 60 * 60)
      3 clf.final_fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, retrain=True)
      4 y = clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
      5 print(y)

/Users/victor/virtualenvlist/mydlp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autokeras/classifier.pyc in fit(self, x_train, y_train, time_limit)
    210         start_time = time.time()
    211         while time.time() - start_time <= time_limit:
--> 212             run_searcher_once(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, self.path)
    213             if len(self.load_searcher().history) >= constant.MAX_MODEL_NUM:
    214                 break

/Users/victor/virtualenvlist/mydlp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autokeras/classifier.pyc in run_searcher_once(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, path)
     41         backend.set_session(sess)
     42     searcher = pickle_from_file(os.path.join(path, 'searcher'))
---> 43     searcher.search(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
     44 
     45 

/Users/victor/virtualenvlist/mydlp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autokeras/search.pyc in search(self, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
    156     def search(self, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test):
    157         if not self.history:
--> 158             self.init_search()
    159 
    160         # Start the new process for training.

/Users/victor/virtualenvlist/mydlp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autokeras/search.pyc in init_search(self)
    142             print('Initializing search.')
    143         graph = DefaultClassifierGenerator(self.n_classes,
--> 144                                            self.input_shape).generate(self.default_model_len,
    145                                                                       self.default_model_width)
    146         model_id = self.model_count

/Users/victor/virtualenvlist/mydlp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autokeras/generator.pyc in __init__(self, n_classes, input_shape)
     34 class DefaultClassifierGenerator(ClassifierGenerator):
     35     def __init__(self, n_classes, input_shape):
---> 36         super().__init__(n_classes, input_shape)
     37 
     38     def generate(self, model_len=constant.MODEL_LEN, model_width=constant.MODEL_WIDTH):

TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```
````

From the log, I think the `fit()` function in class `ImageClassifier` got something wrong. Its init function in ImageClassifier didn't run well.

Someone may encounter this problem and solve it. If could, please share it.

Thanks in Advances.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the code with Python 3.6. Using `super()` without arguments for class inheritance gives your error when running in Python 2.7:

```
class Employee(object): 

    def __init__(self, wage):
        self.wage = wage

class Developer(Employee):
    # inherits from Employee
    def __init__(self, wage):
        super().__init__(wage)

test = Developer(1000)
```

Returns:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

See also the auto-keras [website](http://autokeras.com/start/):

> Installation
>   The installation of Auto-Keras is the same as other python packages. Notably, currently we only support Python 3.6.

Comment: But there is an another error while using Python 3.6.6, when I called  `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` function that the error massage is shown `axes don't match array`. Look at Traceback, https://github.com/jhfjhfj1/autokeras/issues/38

Comment: That's a different issue.

Comment: The above error message `axes don't match array` means I have to reshape it with code `x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))`. But now it's running okay. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote and worked fine on python 3.6:

```
import autokeras as ak
import keras

from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

clf = ak.ImageClassifier(verbose=True)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```